# Run R-Script to get data from GoogleSheets on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, t-sql

This code works fine on Visual Studio

```
OutputDataSet <- read.csv(file = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/128qCX1YtvsHr4hERruFx6Ykn72qRkpRGH5brFULl7SY/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
OutputDataSet
```

I try to send this query using T-SQL

```
DECLARE @GoogleSheetURL nvarchar(500) = 
'OutputDataSet <- read.csv(file = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/128qCX1YtvsHr4hERruFx6Ykn72qRkpRGH5brFULl7SY/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)'

EXEC sp_execute_external_script  
  @language =N'R',    
  @script = @GoogleSheetURL,      
  @input_data_1 = N'   ;'    
  WITH RESULT SETS (([Дата] date,[Отдел] nvarchar(20),[Продукт] nvarchar(20),[Продавец] nvarchar(20),[Выставлено_шт] int,[Оплачено_шт] int,[Выставлено] int,[Оплачено] int ));    
go
```

How it is possible to get data into SQL Server from GoogleSheet?

[ErrorScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ulen.png)
[image]

[VSScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDQUU.jpg)
[image]

Comment: I can't read Russian. BTW, I assume that you are running on SQL Server 2016, because `sp_execute_external_script` is not available on prior versions.

Comment: sp_execute_external_script on SQL Server 2016 is enabled http://prntscr.com/dxio6b     Test R-code works fine  http://prntscr.com/dxioea    Not works reading csv-data from google sheet.  It was written an error msg: "Cannot open connection. Couldn't set up connecting with serve"

Comment: Please post the English translation of the error screen.

Comment: You can try adding `SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH` before the `EXEC` statement for the error messages to be displayed in English.

Comment: Unfortunately, SET LANGUAGE ENGLIS  not affected.       Here is translated error message in Eng http://prntscr.com/dxiykt

Comment: It might be a firewall issue on your SQL Server box.  Can you try opening that url from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer..
There were two  rules in windows firewall
[AnswerScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhKGk.jpg)